# Meaning of Gibbs average

Tags: statistical-mechanics, complex-systems, non-equilibrium

This might sound a very amateur question but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Simply, what is the meaning of Gibbs average? I've came across this term on the paper: Transmission of Information between Complex Networks: 1/f-Resonance (https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.5553) (precisely, in the equation 3; saying that an average is denoting Gibbs average over the fluctuations). But no matter the googling, I couldn't find the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was indeed a simple question. The answer is average non-equilibrium displacement (reference: https://eduardo.physics.illinois.edu/phys582/LRT.pdf)

That link above gives the example of simple harmonic motion. If an external force $F_{\mathrm{ext}}$ is applied, the average displacement (averaging across random internal forces) is given by the following equation:
$$\langle x(t)\rangle= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi(t, t') F_{ext}(t')\, dt',$$
where $\chi$ is the linear response function.

Comment: Hi. If you had this question, someone else will. Check if its not duplicate and write out an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, added explanation.